# Wordpress Elementor Custom Widget with nested Repeaters

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

The ultimate goal is to have a widget for Elementor in Wordpress that can create multiple buttons inside of tabs.  So I want a repeater inside of a repeater.

I do not have all the functionality or styling yet, just the very basic set up that lists each input on the page.  The code I have does not work.  The plugin displays correctly, however all the elementor controls disappear.

[Screenshot of Wordpress page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZVh2.png)

Here is the code:

```html
<?php
namespace Elementor;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/**
 * Elementor iatabs widget.
 *
 * Elementor widget that displays vertical or horizontal iatabs with different
 * pieces of content.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
class Widget_AltTabs extends Widget_Base {

     /**
  * Get widget name.
  *
  * Retrieve iatabs widget name.
  *
  * @since 1.0.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @return string Widget name.
  */
 public function get_name() {
  return 'alttabs';
 }

 /**
  * Get widget title.
  *
  * Retrieve tabs widget title.
  *
  * @since 1.0.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @return string Widget title.
  */
 public function get_title() {
  return __( 'AltTabs', 'elementor' );
 }

 /**
  * Get widget icon.
  *
  * Retrieve tabs widget icon.
  *
  * @since 1.0.0
  * @access public
  *
  * @return string Widget icon.
  */
 public function get_icon() {
  return 'eicon-tabs';
 }

protected function _register_controls() {

$this->start_controls_section(
    'content_section',
    [
        'label' => __( 'Content', 'elementor' ),
        'tab' => Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
    ]
);

$this->add_control(
    'list',
    [
        'label' => __( 'Repeater List', 'elementor' ),
        'type' => Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
        'fields' => [
            [
                'name' => 'list_title',
                'label' => __( 'Title', 'elementor' ),
                'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'default' => __( 'List Title' , 'elementor' ),
                'label_block' => true,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'list_content',
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'elementor' ),
                'type' => Controls_Manager::WYSIWYG,
                'default' => __( 'List Content' , 'elementor' ),
                'show_label' => false,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'list_buttons',
                'label' => __( 'List Buttons', 'elementor' ),
                'type' => Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                'fields' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'button_text',
                        'label' => __( 'Button Text', 'elementor' ),
                        'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                        'default' => __( 'Click' , 'elementor' ),
                        'label_block' => true,
                    ],
                ],
                'default' => [
                    [
                        'button_text' => __( 'Button #1', 'elementor' ),
                    ],
                    [
                        'button_text' => __( 'Button #2', 'elementor' ),
                    ],
                ],
            ],  
        ],
        'default' => [
            [
                'list_title' => __( 'Title #1', 'elementor' ),
                'list_content' => __( 'Item content. Click the edit button to change this text.', 'elementor' ),
            ],
            [
                'list_title' => __( 'Title #2', 'elementor' ),
                'list_content' => __( 'Item content. Click the edit button to change this text.', 'elementor' ),
            ],
        ],
        'title_field' => '{{{ list_title }}}',
    ]
);

$this->end_controls_section();

}

protected function render() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
    if ( $list ) {
        echo '<dl>';
        foreach (  $settings['list'] as $item ) {
            echo '<dt class="repeater-' . $item['_id'] . '">' . $item['list_title'] . '</dt>';
            echo '<dd>' . $item['list_content'] . '</dd>';
            foreach ($item['list_buttons'] as $button) {
                echo $button['button_text'];
            }
        }
        echo '</dl>';
    }
}

 /**
  * Render tabs widget output in the editor.
  *
  * Written as a Backbone JavaScript template and used to generate the live preview.
  *
  * @since 1.0.0
  * @access protected
  */
    protected function _content_template() { ?>
        <# if ( settings.list ) { #>
            <dl>
            <# _.each( settings.list, function( item ) { #>
                <dt class="repeater-{{ item._id }}"> {{ item.list_title }} </dt>
                <dd> {{ item.list_content }} </dd>
                <dd> {{ item.list_buttons[0].button_text }} </dd>

                <# if ( item.list_buttons ) { #>
                    <dl>
                    <# _.each( item.list_buttons, function( i ) { #>
                        <dt class="repeater-{{ i._id }}"> </dt>
                        <dd> {{ i.button_text }} </dd>
                    <# }); #>
                    </dl>
                <# } #>

            <# }); #>
            </dl>
        <# } #>
        <?php
        }

    }
Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new Widget_AltTabs ); ?>
```

Here is an example of the error messages that I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
>       at Object. (editor.min.js?ver=2.0.15:2)
>       at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=underscore,shortcode,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload,jqu&load[]=ery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable&ver=4.9:10)
>       at n.getStyleControls (editor.min.js?ver=2.0.15:2)
>       at editor.min.js?ver=2.0.15:2
>       at Function.m.each.m.forEach (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=underscore,shortcode,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload,jqu&load[]=ery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable&ver=4.9:5)
>       at e.Collection.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=underscore,shortcode,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload,jqu&load[]=ery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable&ver=4.9:18)
>       at Object. (editor.min.js?ver=2.0.15:2)
>       at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=underscore,shortcode,utils,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload,jqu&load[]=ery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable&ver=4.9:10)
>       at n.getStyleControls (editor.min.js?ver=2.0.15:2)
>       at n.renderStyles (editor.min.js?ver=2.0.15:2)<

I am pretty new to writing Elementor widget/plugins so I am stumped here.  I would appreciate any help.  Thank you!

Comment: As the error message statues the `_` in your call `_.each` is undefined. So you're probably missing undersore.js or a similar library.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  Unfortunately that is not the issue because when I remove my inner repeater, everything works just fine.  It is something when I nest the repeater that is going wrong.

Comment: It might be a scoping issue then, that inside the outer loop or some other block the `_` is not defined. I once had similar issues with handlebarsjs

Comment: I ended up using SiteOrigin to create the widget since Elementor is able to use SiteOrigin widgets.  I am familiar with those widgets, it went a lot smoother.  Thanks to everyone who took a look at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeater controls cannot support a nested repeater

take look : https://github.com/pojome/elementor/issues/2955

Comment: Thank you!  This is unfortunate, but I am glad I at least know I am not missing something.
For anyone curious about how I solved this problem, I actually built a SiteOrigin Widget which I then used in Elementor.  It isn't perfect, but my boss and the client were very pleased.

Answer (score -1):

My solution

Create two repeaters and bind them with keys. Good luck

```
protected function _register_controls() {
    $this->start_controls_section(
        'section_categories',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Categories', 'elementor' ),
        ]
    );

    $repeater = new Repeater();

    $repeater->add_control(
        'category_slug',
        [
            'label'       => __( 'Category Slug', 'elementor' ),
            'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'default'     => __( 'category-name', 'elementor' ),
            'label_block' => true,
        ]
    );

    $repeater->add_control(
        'category_title',
        [
            'label'       => __( 'Category Title', 'elementor' ),
            'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'default'     => __( 'Category Title', 'elementor' ),
            'label_block' => true,
        ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
        'categories',
        [
            'label'       => __( 'Contacts', 'elementor' ),
            'type'        => Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
            'fields'      => $repeater->get_controls(),
            'title_field' => '{{{ category_title }}}',
        ]
    );

    $this->end_controls_section();

    $this->start_controls_section(
        'section_prices',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Prices', 'elementor' ),
        ]
    );

    $serviceRepeater = new Repeater();

    $serviceRepeater->add_control(
        'category_slug',
        [
            'label'       => __( 'Category Slug', 'elementor' ),
            'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'default'     => __( 'category-name', 'elementor' ),
            'label_block' => true,
        ]
    );

    $serviceRepeater->add_control(
        'service_title',
        [
            'label'       => __( 'Service Title', 'elementor' ),
            'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'default'     => __( 'Service Title', 'elementor' ),
            'label_block' => true,
        ]
    );

    $serviceRepeater->add_control(
        'service_price',
        [
            'label'       => __( 'Price', 'elementor' ),
            'type'        => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'default'     => __( '40,00', 'elementor' ),
            'label_block' => true,
        ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
        'services',
        [
            'label'       => __( 'Services', 'elementor' ),
            'type'        => Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
            'fields'      => $serviceRepeater->get_controls(),
            'title_field' => '{{{ service_title }}}',
        ]
    );

    $this->end_controls_section();
}
```

Add to render

```
foreach ($settings['categories'] as $category) {
    echo $category['category_title'];

    foreach($settings['services' as $service) {
        if ($category['category_slug'] === $service['category_slug'] {
            echo $category['service_title'];
        }
    }
}
```